# How do I change the background of every single header (expandable listview)?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, expandablelistview

I have an expandable listview and I want to change the background of every single header it has. It has 4 headers. This is how I want it to look:
[image]

How do I change the background of all four headers and then add my custom 'green arrow' to it? The main part right now is to change the background of headers, the green arrow is just a bonus answer :)

Comment: You're being downvoted because your question shows no research effort...

Comment: In the first place, do you know how you got the group headers there? If you know, then just apply your background in the place where you create your group header views.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem:

```
switch(groupPosition){
    case 0:
        convertView.setBackground(this._context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.light_blue));
        break;
    case 1:
        convertView.setBackground(this._context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drugi_letniki_color));
        break;
    case 2:
        convertView.setBackground(this._context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.light_blue));
        break;
    case 3:
        convertView.setBackground(this._context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cetrti_letniki_color));
        break;
    }
```

groupPosition is integer variable from getGroupView method